# SQL Query to summarise a table of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with the following data in:

```
ID |  JobNumber     | UserID  | Date                 | Task
1        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:00    Task 1
2        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:10    Task 2
3        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:20    Task 3
4        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:30    Task 4
5        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:40    Task 5
6        1            user1     02/05/2014 08:00:50    Task 6
7        2            user1     02/05/2014 09:00:00    Task 1
8        2            user1     02/05/2014 09:00:10    Task 2
9        3            user1     02/05/2014 09:15:00    Task 1
10       3            user1     02/05/2014 09:15:45    Task 2
11       1            user2     02/05/2014 09:02:10    Task 1
12       1            user2     02/05/2014 09:02:25    Task 2
13       1            user1     02/05/2014 12:00:00    Task 10
14       1            user1     02/05/2014 12:00:10    Task 11
```

I will run a query each day, that will go through the above and work out the totals. What I need to do is for each User work out how long they have been working on each JobNumber so the above would give me the following:

```
UserId  | JobNumber  |  TotalTime
user1     1             00:01:00
user1     2             00:00:10
user1     3             00:00:45
user2     1             00:00:15
```

I'm wondering if using a rownumber to then subtract the maximum and minimum dates for that group, but not too sure how I go about this.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using Report Builder 3.0

Comment: It is SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use row number here.. Just use group by

```
select userid, jobnumber, cast(max(date)-min(date) as time)
from table1
group by userid, jobnumber
order by userid
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a80cb/4)

Comment: The problem I have with this is for example if we take user1 and JobNumber1 it is taking the last time as 12:00:10 and the first time as 08:00:00 and saying the user has spent 04:00:10 on that job, but they haven't they have spent 00:01:00

Comment: @user3219693 So there should be another column indicating when someone started and stopped working (in your example `user1` would start `job1` at 08:00:00 and finish at 08:00:50 and then start again at 12:00:00 and finish at 12:00:10). You can try creating a difficult query against the data that you have now, but adding another column seems like the most effective thing to do.

Comment: Unfortunately the option to add columns is non existent, I need to try and get out what I need from what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the format as number of seconds:

```
select userid, jobnumber, datediff(second, min(date), max(date)) as TimeInSeconds
from table t
group by userid, jobnumber;
```

Transforming this back to a time format depends on the version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: This gives me the same issue as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point: (you might want to use DATEDIFF to get how much time spent in hours for example.

```
SELECT  JobStartTimes.JobNumber ,
        JobStartTimes.UserID ,
        JobEndTimes.EndTime - JobStartTimes.StartTime AS TimeElapsed
FROM    ( SELECT    JobNumber ,
                    UserID ,
                    MIN(Date) AS StartTime
          FROM      Jobs
          GROUP BY  JobNumber ,
                    UserID
        ) AS JobStartTimes
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT JobNumber ,
                            UserID ,
                            MAX(Date) AS EndTime
                     FROM   Jobs
                     GROUP BY JobNumber ,
                            UserID
                   ) AS JobEndTimes ON (
                                         JobStartTimes.JobNumber = JobEndTimes.JobNumber
                                         AND JobStartTimes.UserID = JobEndTimes.UserID
                                       )
```

Comment: This gives me the same issue as above

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLServer 2012 or better, and if the duration of each task is bounded by the current and the next value of the date column, as its seems from your comment to G one then the following will get what you asked for

```
WITH schedule AS (
  SELECT JobNumber
       , UserID
       , TaskBegin = Task
       , TaskEnd = LEAD([task], 1, [task]) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY jobnumber, userid ORDER BY date)
       , DateBegin = [date]
       , DateEnd = LEAD([date], 1, [date]) 
                   OVER (PARTITION BY jobnumber, userid ORDER BY date)
  FROM   Jobs)
SELECT UserID
     , JobNumber
     , Duration
     = CAST(DATEADD(ss, SUM(CASE WHEN TaskEnd > TaskBegin 
                                 THEN DATEDIFF(ss, DateBegin, DateEnd)
                                 ELSE 0
                            END), 0) AS Time)
FROM   Schedule
GROUP BY JobNumber, UserID
```

The `CTE` is only to make the query easier to read, the definition of the `TaskBegin`, `TaskEnd`, `DateBegin` and `DateEnd` can replace the aliases in the main query.
The `Case` is necessary to split job lists for the same `UserID` and `JobNumber`, as the last two line in the example data.
The `DATEDIFF` return an interger, that cannot be casted to `Time`, to do this a fake conversion through is needed, if the results in second is enough the `CAST(DATEADD` part can be stripped away

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1b61/25) demo, the demo has different aliases

**Update**
As the database is a SQLServer 2008 the query will become a little more complex

```
With Tasks As (
  SELECT ID
       , jobnumber
       , userid
       , jobdate
       , task_num = Replace(Task, 'Task ', '')
       , Ord = Row_Number () OVER (PARTITION BY JobNumber, UserID 
                                   ORDER BY JobDate)
  FROM   jobs
)
SELECT t1.UserId
     , t1.jobnumber
     , Duration 
     = Cast(DateAdd(ss, Sum(DateDiff(ss, t1.JobDate, t2.JobDate)), 0) as Time)
FROM   Tasks t1
       INNER JOIN Tasks t2 ON t1.jobnumber = t2.jobnumber
                          AND t1.userid = t2.userid
                          AND t1.task_num = t2.task_num - 1
                          AND t1.Ord = t2.ord - 1
GROUP BY t1.UserId, t1.jobnumber
ORDER BY t1.UserId, t1.jobnumber
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6192/44) for the SQLServer 2008 query

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Report Builder 3.0 and LEAD is not recognized.